# Identify a lone bone (jaw including teeth) found on a beach at Trouville-sur-Mer (France) in 2018

Tags: species-identification, bone-biology

Found this on the beach at Trouville-sur-Mer in France, on 11 May 2018. It was laying in the sand, close to a trash can. Considering the strong smell of sand within the skeleton, it must have been near the sea for a very long time.

---

What species is this from?

Also posted on other identification websites and fora:

- https://www.inaturalist.org/observations/14323892
- https://observation.org/waarneming/view/160056539
- https://forum.waarneming.nl/smf/index.php?topic=431852.0
- http://www.nhm.ac.uk/natureplus/message/115302/

---

The length of the bone (the piece remaining) is **under 12 centimeter**.

The height of the only easily removable tooth (the smallest remaining one) is **under 25 milimeter**.

---

### **Old pictures in sunlight (all in low resolution & without measure bar):**

Click the images for enlargement.

[image]
   
[image]
 
[image]

---

### **Update of 22 July 2018 (most in higher resolution & with measure bar):**

This new set of pictures is [archived at Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Jaw_with_teeth_(lone_animal_bone)_found_on_beach_of_Trouville-sur-Mer_on_11_May_2018).

- *Jaw with teeth (lone animal bone) found on beach of Trouville-sur-Mer in France on 11 May 2018, length smaller than 12cm, **side A**, photographed on 22 July 2018 - **Image 1 of 3***

[image: File:Jaw with teeth (lone animal bone) found on beach of Trouville-sur-Mer in France on 11 May 2018, length smaller than 12cm, side A, photographed on 22 July 2018 - Image 1 of 3.png]

See [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Jaw_with_teeth_(lone_animal_bone)_found_on_beach_of_Trouville-sur-Mer_in_France_on_11_May_2018,_length_smaller_than_12cm,_side_A,_photographed_on_22_July_2018_-_Image_1_of_3.png) for a higher resolution.

- *Jaw with teeth (lone animal bone) found on beach of Trouville-sur-Mer in France on 11 May 2018, length smaller than 12cm, **side A**, photographed on 22 July 2018 - **Image 2 of 3***

[image: File:Jaw with teeth (lone animal bone) found on beach of Trouville-sur-Mer in France on 11 May 2018, length smaller than 12cm, side A, photographed on 22 July 2018 - Image 2 of 3.png]

See [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Jaw_with_teeth_(lone_animal_bone)_found_on_beach_of_Trouville-sur-Mer_in_France_on_11_May_2018,_length_smaller_than_12cm,_side_A,_photographed_on_22_July_2018_-_Image_2_of_3.png) for a higher resolution.

- *Jaw with teeth (lone animal bone) found on beach of Trouville-sur-Mer in France on 11 May 2018, length smaller than 12cm, **side A**, photographed on 22 July 2018 - **Image 3 of 3***

[image: File:Jaw with teeth (lone animal bone) found on beach of Trouville-sur-Mer in France on 11 May 2018, length smaller than 12cm, side A, photographed on 22 July 2018 - Image 3 of 3.png]

See [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Jaw_with_teeth_(lone_animal_bone)_found_on_beach_of_Trouville-sur-Mer_in_France_on_11_May_2018,_length_smaller_than_12cm,_side_A,_photographed_on_22_July_2018_-_Image_3_of_3.png) for a higher resolution.

- *Jaw with teeth (lone animal bone) found on beach of Trouville-sur-Mer in France on 11 May 2018, length smaller than 12cm, **side B**, photographed on 22 July 2018 - **Image 1 of 2***

[image: File:Jaw with teeth (lone animal bone) found on beach of Trouville-sur-Mer in France on 11 May 2018, length smaller than 12cm, side B, photographed on 22 July 2018 - Image 1 of 2.png]

See [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Jaw_with_teeth_(lone_animal_bone)_found_on_beach_of_Trouville-sur-Mer_in_France_on_11_May_2018,_length_smaller_than_12cm,_side_B,_photographed_on_22_July_2018_-_Image_1_of_2.png) for a higher resolution.

- *Jaw with teeth (lone animal bone) found on beach of Trouville-sur-Mer in France on 11 May 2018, length smaller than 12cm, **side B**, photographed on 22 July 2018 - **Image 2 of 2***

[image: File:Jaw with teeth (lone animal bone) found on beach of Trouville-sur-Mer in France on 11 May 2018, length smaller than 12cm, side B, photographed on 22 July 2018 - Image 2 of 2.png]

See [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Jaw_with_teeth_(lone_animal_bone)_found_on_beach_of_Trouville-sur-Mer_in_France_on_11_May_2018,_length_smaller_than_12cm,_side_B,_photographed_on_22_July_2018_-_Image_2_of_2.png) for a higher resolution.

- Jaw with teeth (lone animal bone) found on beach of Trouville-sur-Mer in France on 11 May 2018, length smaller than 12cm, **top side**, photographed on 22 July 2018 - **Image 1 of 3**

[image: File:Jaw with teeth (lone animal bone) found on beach of Trouville-sur-Mer in France on 11 May 2018, length smaller than 12cm, top side, photographed on 22 July 2018 - Image 1 of 3.png]

See [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Jaw_with_teeth_(lone_animal_bone)_found_on_beach_of_Trouville-sur-Mer_in_France_on_11_May_2018,_length_smaller_than_12cm,_top_side,_photographed_on_22_July_2018_-_Image_1_of_3.png) for a higher resolution.

- Jaw with teeth (lone animal bone) found on beach of Trouville-sur-Mer in France on 11 May 2018, length smaller than 12cm, **top side**, photographed on 22 July 2018 - **Image 2 of 3**

[image: File:Jaw with teeth (lone animal bone) found on beach of Trouville-sur-Mer in France on 11 May 2018, length smaller than 12cm, top side, photographed on 22 July 2018 - Image 2 of 3.png]

See [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Jaw_with_teeth_(lone_animal_bone)_found_on_beach_of_Trouville-sur-Mer_in_France_on_11_May_2018,_length_smaller_than_12cm,_top_side,_photographed_on_22_July_2018_-_Image_2_of_3.png) for a higher resolution.

- Jaw with teeth (lone animal bone) found on beach of Trouville-sur-Mer in France on 11 May 2018, length smaller than 12cm, **top side**, photographed on 22 July 2018 - **Image 3 of 3**

[image: File:Jaw with teeth (lone animal bone) found on beach of Trouville-sur-Mer in France on 11 May 2018, length smaller than 12cm, top side, photographed on 22 July 2018 - Image 3 of 3.png]

See [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Jaw_with_teeth_(lone_animal_bone)_found_on_beach_of_Trouville-sur-Mer_in_France_on_11_May_2018,_length_smaller_than_12cm,_top_side,_photographed_on_22_July_2018_-_Image_3_of_3.png) for a higher resolution.

- Smallest remaining tooth from jaw (lone animal bone) found on beach of Trouville-sur-Mer in France on 11 May 2018, height smaller than 25mm, **side B**, photographed on 22 July 2018 - **Image 1 of 2**

[image: File:Smallest remaining tooth from jaw (lone animal bone) found on beach of Trouville-sur-Mer in France on 11 May 2018, height smaller than 25mm, side B, photographed on 22 July 2018 - Image 1 of 2.png]

See [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Smallest_remaining_tooth_from_jaw_(lone_animal_bone)_found_on_beach_of_Trouville-sur-Mer_in_France_on_11_May_2018,_height_smaller_than_25mm,_side_B,_photographed_on_22_July_2018_-_Image_1_of_2.png) for a higher resolution.

- Smallest remaining tooth from jaw (lone animal bone) found on beach of Trouville-sur-Mer in France on 11 May 2018, height smaller than 25mm, **side B**, photographed on 22 July 2018 - **Image 2 of 2**

[image: File:Smallest remaining tooth from jaw (lone animal bone) found on beach of Trouville-sur-Mer in France on 11 May 2018, height smaller than 25mm, side B, photographed on 22 July 2018 - Image 2 of 2.png]

See [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Smallest_remaining_tooth_from_jaw_(lone_animal_bone)_found_on_beach_of_Trouville-sur-Mer_in_France_on_11_May_2018,_height_smaller_than_25mm,_side_B,_photographed_on_22_July_2018_-_Image_2_of_2.png) for a higher resolution.

Comment: Can you do a close up shot of the teeth from above, so we can see the crown layout, that is one of the main ways to identify mammal material.

Comment: Sasquatch for sure :p.

Comment: @John I have now added new pictures, including the teeth from above.

Answer (score 3):

It would be great to have a scale bar in the photo, so that the size would be easier to determine. However, by the shape of the teeth, I will propose that it is the back half of the jaw of a pig. Here is an [image](http://collections.rmg.co.uk/collections/objects/2908.html) from the National Maritime Museum:

[image: Pig]

This one is from Vanuatu and has a rather elaborate mesial portion of the jaw, but the teeth look very similar. It's virtually impossible to know the bone's age or species, however.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, posting these images on Identification apps/websites/fora, I also became aware of the usefulness of a scale bar. Within a couple of weeks, I can take high-resolution pictures with a scale bar. --- Do you think any conservation archive, museum or researcher could be interested in analysing or conserving the specimen? How would I be able to find such an interested party easily?

Comment: without knowing what rock it came out of there is not a lot that can be done scientifically with what you have. Although someone might be interested in trying to figure out where i eroded out from. Contact the nearest natural history museum.

Comment: I agree with @John. Without additional provenance information, it's not much use scientifically. However that does not mean that a local museum would not be interested in it for display.

Comment: @kmm I have added new pictures, which show the bone with teeth from above and also feature a scale bar. Please update your answer if appropriate.